# Power 5mm LEDs with 5V adapter instead of 2xAA?

Tags: voltage, led, resistors

I have a model of the Eiffel Tower illuminated with 5mm LEDs that are powered by 2 AA batteries. The LEDs come prewired with resistors and heatshrink.

Basically I want to use on of the many 5v phone chargers I have lying around to power it and use it as a nightlight.

Can you help me calculate the proper resistance to add so the LEDs get the right current, which I guess is about 15 mAh, after the increase in voltage?

Thanks!

Comment: In all practicality, you can probably just power your LEDs directly from 5V with no problem. If you insist on being "right" about it, we need more information. What is the resistor value that is pre-wired with the LEDs? Are the LEDs in series or parallel? How many of them are there?

Comment: If you don't know the resistance and type of LED, do you have access to a multimeter to measure the current when used with batteries? That would be enough to know the extra resistance required for the additional voltage to keep things the same.

Comment: 2 AA batteries should equal to about 3V. And 15mAh is a measure of capacity, not current.

Comment: @Brendan Simpson No No! You can't put 5V instead of 3V. You risk damaging the LEDs.

Comment: J. Doe What are the color of the LEDs? And how many exactly? Maybe one 1W, or 2W resistor is enough for the whole thing if the total current is not too big.

Comment: @Fredled The resistor will just dissipate the extra power. Sure, the current will be a little bit higher, but I highly doubt it would cause any real problems with a circuit like this. Until the OP can provide some technical information about their circuit, this is pure speculation, therefore I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Brendan Simpson I disagree: The resistors will dissipate more power, causing more heating which is not good. But the leds will also recieve more voltage than necessary despite the resistors, and they will heat too much too. That being said, as this is not vital equipement, He can try with 5V directly. It will be very bright, but if it burns in a few days or a fter a few seconds, that's it. :)